# How do I populate my UITableView with Facebook Profile Photos

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've been stuck on this for days and after searching high and low for answers on Stackoverflow and looking through code on GitHub, I'm at my wits end.

I'm trying to get a Facebook Profile picture to show up with other data in a UITableView.  I'm using the following code.  The score shows up, the Facebook profile name shows up, but the image does not show.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];


    [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/scores?fields=score,user", appID] parameters:nil HTTPMethod:@"GET" completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {

        if (result && !error)
        {
            for (NSDictionary *dict in [result objectForKey:@"data"])
            {
                NSString *name = [[dict objectForKey:@"user"] objectForKey:@"name"];
                NSString *strScore = [dict objectForKey:@"score"];
                NSString *profilePictureID = [[dict objectForKey:@"user"] objectForKey:@"id"];
                NSString *profilePicture = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/picture?width=80&height=80&redirect=false",profilePictureID];
                NSString *url = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture",profilePictureID];
                UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]]];
                NSLog(@"The URL is %@.  The image URL is %@", url, image);
                [url release];
                NSLog(@"This message is in the UITableViewCell and will hopefully show the name %@ and the score %@ along with %@ as the profile picture URL.", name, strScore, profilePicture);

                // DID NOT WORK - cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", image]];
                // DID NOT WORK - cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", profilePicturel]];

                cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", url]];

                cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", name];
                cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Score: %@", strScore];

            }
        }

    }];

    return cell;
}
```

My NSLog messsages are returning the following data.

```
- The URL is https://graph.facebook.com/xxxxx/picture.  The image URL is <UIImage: 0xdee1234>

- This message is in the UITableViewCell and will hopefully show the name xxxxx and the score xxxxx along with xxxxx/picture?width=80&height=80&redirect=false as the profile picture URL.
```

I've tried a dozen different ways to get the Facebook profile photos to work and I thought this one would considering it is the first time that I got back a log message like this.

I would appreciate any help or suggestions on how to get this working.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have already retrieved the image (if it exists) with this line:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]]];
```

So all you need to do is set it:

```
cell.imageView.image = image;
```

The method `imageNamed:` is only needed if you are trying to load an image from a file in your project.

One thing to note though, `NSData`'s `dataWithContentsofURL:` method is synchronous. You are going to be blocking the main thread with this approach. You'd be better off doing all of this work first, storing the data in an array, and then reloading the tableView using that array as the data source.

Comment: It worked!  Getting rid of the imagedNamed did the trick.  You are awesome!  I'm new to all this. I came so close and I knew somebody who knew what they were doing could tell me what I was doing wrong in a few minutes.  Thank you!  I would love to do what you suggested with the array.  What would be the best way to do that?  Would I create another .h &.m file with that array or would I put it somewhere in the current file?  What would the array look like and how would I go about pulling the data back into the tableView?